# Unable to use Ubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10 Version 1803 and it appeared to install properly. Normally when it first comes up it will prompt for a username and password and then let you do whatever you want. In this case the Ubuntu window closes down immediately both after the continuation in the initial install and after trying to invoke it from the task bar. I have successfully installed it on a prior  setup of Windows 10 version 1803. What should I look for that might prevent me using Ubuntu?

Comment: **Irrelevant Side Note:** Windows 10 1903 added some more new features for WSL. Consider upgrading Windows 10 to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the optional Windows 10 feature WSL must be enabled before trying to use Ubuntu. Fixing this fixed the problem.